# ¿Cómo agregar varios elementos en la lista en python?

Tags: python, lista

sé que existe el método append para agregar elementos a una lista en python de que otra manera se puede agregar varios elementos a una lista sin hacerlo uno a uno

```
    scores_list.append(TFA1)
    scores_list.append(TFA2) 
    scores_list.append(TFH1)
    scores_list.append(TFH2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar el método [`extend()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) que espera un *iterable*, por ejemplo otra lista, que creas "al vuelo":

```
scores_list.extend([TFA, TFA2, TFH1, TFH2])
```

Que es equivalente a:

```
scores_list[len(scores_list):] = [TFA, TFA2, TFH1, TFH2]
```

O incluso podrías resolverlo de forma más explícita mediante un `for`:

```
for e in [TFA, TFA2, TFH1, TFH2]:
    scores_list.append(e)
```

Comment: Aunque la opcion mas viable es usar extend otra opción sería sumar las listas, `scores_list+=[TFA, TFA2, TFH1, TFH2]`, funcionaria también sin problema pero te recomendaria comprobar que ambos sean listas si no estas seguro de tu tipo de dato.

Comment: extend no es para agregar una lista en otra? [[TFA, TFA2, TFH1, TFH2], "Hola"]

Comment: @NicollMejia, No, `extend()` es para agregar los elementos de una lista a otra, Por ejemplo: `lista = [1];lista.extend([2,3,4]);print(lista)` el resultado es `[1,2,3,4]`

Comment: Gracias, yo habia visto este método pero pensé que quedaba una lista en otra.